# ERROR Mixing of Group Columns with No Group Columns

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I got this error and I'm not sure how to work with it. Simple explanations would be much appreciated. Error:

Error Number: 1140

```
Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause

SELECT a.nim,b.nama_mahasiswa,c.j_sks,b.jurusan,b.kelas_program,e.status from tbl_dosen_wali a left join tbl_mahasiswa b on a.nim=b.nim left join (select k.nim,k.kd_jadwal,SUM(l.jum_sks) as j_sks from tbl_perwalian_detail k left join (select x.kd_jadwal, y.jum_sks from tbl_jadwal x left join tbl_mk y on x.kd_mk=y.kd_mk) as l on k.kd_jadwal=l.kd_jadwal) c on a.nim=c.nim left join tbl_perwalian_header e on a.nim=e.nim where a.kd_dosen='D001' group by a.nim

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\krs\siakad\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

Formatted Query:

```
SELECT a.nim,
       b.nama_mahasiswa,
       c.j_sks,
       b.jurusan,
       b.kelas_program,
       e.status
FROM   tbl_dosen_wali a
       LEFT JOIN tbl_mahasiswa b
              ON a.nim = b.nim
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT k.nim,
                         k.kd_jadwal,
                         Sum(l.jum_sks) AS j_sks
                  FROM   tbl_perwalian_detail k
                         LEFT JOIN (SELECT x.kd_jadwal,
                                           y.jum_sks
                                    FROM   tbl_jadwal x
                                           LEFT JOIN tbl_mk y
                                                  ON x.kd_mk = y.kd_mk) AS l
                                ON k.kd_jadwal = l.kd_jadwal) c
              ON a.nim = c.nim
       LEFT JOIN tbl_perwalian_header e
              ON a.nim = e.nim
WHERE  a.kd_dosen = 'D001'
GROUP  BY a.nim
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244169/mysql-1140-mixing-of-group-columns  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547802/mixing-of-group-columns-min-max-count-with-no-group-columns-is-illeg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712408/mixing-of-group-columns-with-no-group-columns

Answer (score 0):

as the error said you need to use GROUP BY in your subquery.

try this

```
   SELECT a.nim,
   b.nama_mahasiswa,
   c.j_sks,
   b.jurusan,
   b.kelas_program,
   e.status
 FROM   tbl_dosen_wali a
   LEFT JOIN tbl_mahasiswa b
          ON a.nim = b.nim
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT k.nim,
                     k.kd_jadwal,
                     Sum(l.jum_sks) AS j_sks
              FROM   tbl_perwalian_detail k
                     LEFT JOIN (SELECT x.kd_jadwal,
                                       y.jum_sks
                                FROM   tbl_jadwal x
                                       LEFT JOIN tbl_mk y
                                              ON x.kd_mk = y.kd_mk) AS l
                            ON k.kd_jadwal = l.kd_jadwal
                            GROUP  BY k.nim 
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                           ) c
          ON a.nim = c.nim
   LEFT JOIN tbl_perwalian_header e
          ON a.nim = e.nim
 WHERE  a.kd_dosen = 'D001'
 GROUP  BY a.nim
```